# Django custom manager for Profile with calculated field

Tags: python, django

I want to add a calculated field for users profile.
I adding a custom manager:

```
class ProCalcManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        result = super(ProCalcManager, self).get_queryset()
        result = result.extra(
        select={'pro': "(start_date, INTERVAL '10 days') OVERLAPS"
                       "(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL '1 days')"}
        )
        return result

class Profile (models.Model):

    objects = ProCalcManager()
    default_manager = ProCalcManager()

    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

And when I use: `Users.objects.first().profile.pro` result is `True`, but for `Users.objects.filter(profile__pro=True)` result is `{TypeError} Related Field got invalid lookup: pro`

How I can another update queryset for adding calculated field "pro" in user profile for use it in filter?

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, from what i understand the `pro` field is literally _startdate + 10 days > current date_ there is no need to use `extra`, you can do it using filter too.

Comment: yes, but this filter must be used in many places in our system, so I would like to place a filter in one place of model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you are doing is calculating date and then determining if the user is `pro` or not. Instead of going through the trouble of writing sql statements for both, calculation and filtering, you can use simple `.filter()` to achieve it.

Firstly, Instead of overriding `get_queryset()` method, add a property named `pro` in your model.

```
@property
def pro(self):
    calculated_end_date = tz.now() + tz.timedelta(days=-10)
    return self.start_date > calculated_end_date
```

By doing this, you'll be able to access the `pro` property of a profile. Just like you do with extra.

```
>>> p = Profile.objects.first()
>>> p.pro
>>> True
```

Then for being able to filter profiles for their `pro` values, you can write a queryset for than and use it as a manager instead. Something like this:

```
class ProCalcQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def is_pro(self, value=True):
        calculated_end_date = tz.now() + tz.timedelta(days=-10)
        if value:
            lookup = 'gte'
        else:
            lookup = 'lt'
        filter_dict = {
            'start_date__' + lookup: calculated_end_date
        }
        return self.filter(**filter_dict)
```

Then use this queryset as a manager to access it in model objects

```
class Profile (models.Model):

    objects = ProCalcQuerySet.as_manager()
    default_manager = ProCalcQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
In [2]: Profile.objects.is_pro(value=True)
Out[2]: [<Profile: Profile object>]

In [3]: Profile.objects.is_pro()
Out[3]: [<Profile: Profile object>]

In [4]: Profile.objects.is_pro(False)
Out[4]: []

In [8]: Profile.objects.is_pro().first().pro
Out[8]: True
```